# writing string in utf8 format to zip file ( Ionic.Zip )

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem that output string must be utf8-formatted, I am writing currently ansi  string to zip file without problems like this:

```
StreamReader tr = new StreamReader( "myutf8-file.xml");
String myfilecontent = tr.ReadToEnd();
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile());
zip.AddFileFromString("my.xml", "", myfilecontent  );
```

How to force string (my.xml file content) to be UTF8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use the deprecated `AddFileFromString` method. Use [`AddEntry(string, string, string, Encoding)`](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/35f20a5f-fc44-91ab-bda9-8502b59f5cd6.htm) instead:

```
zip.AddEntry("my.xml", "", myfilecontent, Encoding.UTF8);
```

If you're *actually* reading a UTF-8 text file to start with though, why not just open the stream and pass *that* into `AddEntry`? There's no need to decode from UTF-8 and then re-encode...